# Oracle substing with error 00917. 00000 - "missing comma"

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

In Oracle, when I use `SUBSTR()` in merge, there's an error saying "missing comma". I can't find out, where do I need a comma, or do I use the wrong clause?

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT INTO A      
        (
        A.EMP_ID,
        A.HOLI_DATE,
        A.HOLI_HOURS,
        A.HOLI_REASON,
        A.START_TIME,
        A.END_TIME,
        A.AGENT_EMP_ID,
        A.VERSION,
        A.CREATETIME,
        --,TG.CREATOR
        --,TG.MODIFIER
        A.LASTUPDATE)
VALUES
 substr(B.EMP_ID,3,6)as EMP_ID,--this is the line with error"missing 
 comma"
        B.HOLI_DATE,
        B.HOLI_HOURS,
        B.HOLI_REASON,
        SUBSTR(B.HOLI_TIME,1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(B.HOLI_TIME,3,2) AS 
START_TIME,
        SUBSTR(B.HOLI_TIME,6,2)||':'||SUBSTR(B.HOLI_TIME,8,2) AS 
END_TIME,
        SUBSTR(B.AGENT_EMP_ID,3,6) AS AGENT_EMP_ID,
        1,
        sysdate,
        --,$$PLSQL_UNIT
        --,$$PLSQL_UNIT
        sysdate
FROM B
```

Comment: Just remove `comma"` two lines below from `VALUES` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `INTO A` after `INSERT`
the Syntax in a merge statement is:

```
merge into A
  using(select col1, col2, col3... from B)
  on (A.col1 = B.value1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1,col2...)
    VALUES (B.value1, B.value2...)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET col2= B.value2
...
```

Don't forget parenthesis around value list